# php code consolidation

Tags: php

I was troubleshooting some code and ended up with this:

```
$url=$this->_protected_arr['f3b'];
$title=$this->_protected_arr['f3a'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
database::query("INSERT INTO bo VALUES ('$title','$url','','$email')");
```

I think that it should be abel to get rid of $url, $title, and $email and just insert their values directly into the query.  How do I write this in a single statement?

Comment: You should be using prepared statements rather than interpolating values directly into the statement. If `database` doesn't support prepared statements, find a modern DB query module.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to change its meaning, you should post a new question.  If you change your question's meaning, the answers will no longer make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
database::query("INSERT INTO bo VALUES ('{$this->_protected_arr[f3b]}', '{$this->_protected_arr[f3a]}', '', '$_SESSION[email]')");
```

Be sure that everything is properly escaped for the SQL query.

Comment: Yep, now it should work. Sorry for that. I didn't realize that member variable access is different. So for the member arrays we use the brace notation (which you can always use, by the way), but for the free `$_SESSION` array I use the shorter, unquoted version -- but you may use braces here too for consistency if you like.

Comment: are the braces a sql or a php thing?

Comment: A PHP thing. Read up about variable substitution inside doubly-quoted strings, that's what's going on here.

Comment: Ohh, actually you can even omit the quotation marks inside the braces, too. Let me edit once more.

Answer (score 1):

```
database::query("INSERT INTO bo VALUES ('"
                . $this->_protected_arr[f3b] . "', '"
                . $this->_protected_arr[f3a] . "', '', '"
                . $_SESSION[email]."')");
```

Comment: A query is simply a line of text, you can add variables into text just like any other variable. eg. echo "hello ".$var1." my name is ".$var2;